Regarding Problem 5 on p. 8 of Bredon's Topology and Geometry
In page 8, Section 2: Topological Spaces of Bredon's Topology and Geometry, he presents the 5th question as follows:

Suppose that $S$ is a set and that we are given, for each $x \in S$, a collection $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ of subsets of $S$ satisfying:

$N \in \mathfrak{N}(x) \implies x \in N$,
$N,M \in \mathfrak{N}(x) \implies \exists P\in\mathfrak{N}(x)$ s.t. $P\subseteq(N \cap M)$, and
$x \in S \implies \mathfrak{N}(x) \neq \varnothing$.


Then show that there is a unique topology on $S$ such that $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ is a neighborhood basis at $x$, for each $x \in S$. (Thus a topology can be defined by the specification of such a collection of neighborhoods at each point.)

Now, what I have attempted the first time was to take $\{\mathfrak{N}(x) | x \in S\}$ as a subbasis (acting upon the comment in the parentheses), show that its topology (let $\tau$) makes each $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ a neighborhood basis at $x$ and it is the unique topology that does this.
But, in this attempt, I realized I needed to describe $\tau$ and while attempting I couldn't conclude that $\tau$ makes each $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ a neighborhood basis at $x$ for each $x$ as I couldn't show an open set $U$ containing $x$ with $U \subseteq N \in \mathfrak{N}(x)$.
Next I thought that since neighborhoods do not need to be open sets themselves, it is more natural to take
\begin{equation}\tag{Eq. 1}
\bigcup\limits_{x \in S} \left \{\mathfrak{N}(x) \right \} = \{\mathfrak{N}(x_1) \} \cup \{ \mathfrak{N}(x_2)\} \cup \dots
\end{equation} as a subbasis, i.e. union of elements of $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ for each $x \in S$.
Here I think I proved that $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ is a neighborhood basis at $x$ for each $x \in S$, let $x \in S$ be given, then:

All elements in $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ are open and they contain $x$, so they are neighborhoods of $x$ by default,
Given any neighborhood of $x$, let $K$, I have to show that for some $N \in \mathfrak{N}(x)$, $N \subseteq K$. Since $K$ is a n'hood of $x$, there exists an open set $U$ s.t. $x \in U \subseteq K$. Since $U$ is open wrt to the topology we have generated, $U$ is arbitrary union of finite intersections of elements of Eq.1. And since we can get open sets containing $x$ specifically from intersecting $N$'s from the same $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ (not like intersecting $N \in \mathfrak{N}(x_1)$ and $M \in \mathfrak{N}(x_2)$ where $x_1 \neq x_2$ and $x$ is an element of both), for some $N \in \mathfrak{N}(x)$, $N \subseteq U$, thus $N \subseteq K$. Hence $K$ contains an element from the neighborhood basis.

I am sorry if the second point is not very precise. But is my reasoning sound and valid and how do I go on and prove existence of such a topology? Can I somehow prove that it is the finest/coarsest topology instantiates the condition, does that imply uniqueness?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Attempt at a Proof Upon @Thorgott 's Comment
To make $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ a n'hood basis at $x$, we must have the following, every set in $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ is a n'hood of $x$, and any n'hood of of $x$ contains a set from $\mathfrak{N}(x)$. Maybe, we can define an open set as accepting the sets in $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ as neighborhoods of $x$ and later check that this definition of open sets verifies the second condition of $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ being a n'hood basis. Then, let:
\begin{equation}
    \text{A subset } U \subseteq S \text{ is open if } \mathfrak{N}(x) \subseteq U \quad \forall x \in U.
\end{equation}
Observe that since $U$ contains a n'hood for every one of its points, it is a n'hood for its points. Hence we satisfy the openness characterization by neighborhoods. This way, we get the topology, denote it by $\tau$. Now the difficult part. We must show that: (1) $\tau$ is a well-defined topology, and (2) $\tau$ makes $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ a n'hood basis at $x$ for each $x \in S$, and (3) $\tau$ is unique.
For (1), it is easy to see that countable intersection of open sets is again open. The space itself contains $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ for all $x \in S$, thus it is open, and $\varnothing$ is vacuously open because $\mathfrak{N}() \subseteq \varnothing$. For arbitrary unions of open sets, since we are collecting over $\mathfrak{N}(x)$'s we'll still have openness. Thus $\tau$ is a well-defined topology.
For (2), we should check the second condition for $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ to be a n'hood basis, as the first condition is already given by definition. I.e. given a n'hood $N$ of a point $x \in S$, can we find an element $K$ in $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ such that $K \subseteq N$? If $N$ is a n'hood, then it contains an open set, let $U$, such that $x$ is contained within. By def'n of our openness, $U$ contains $\mathfrak{N}(x)$, and since $\mathfrak{N}(x) \neq \varnothing$, we definitely have such a set $K$ such that $K \subseteq N$. Thus $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ is a n'hood basis at $x$ for each $x \in S$.
For (3), why is that $\tau$ is unique? Because every open set is uniquely determined by its points, as its points uniquely determine $\mathfrak{N}(x)$. I believe this unique determination is mainly due to the first and second properties of definition of $\mathfrak{N}(x)$, as given $x \in S$, we can find non-empty sets in $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ such that they are subsets of intersections of sets in $\mathfrak{N}(x)$. And this property holds only for $k$ if $\mathfrak{N}(x = k)$. Thus uniqueness.
2nd Attempt
Motivated by the neighborhood characterization of openness, define a set $U$ as open if
\begin{equation}
\forall x \in U \; \; \exists N \in \mathfrak{N}(x) \text{ s.t. } N \subseteq U.
\end{equation}
Then, is $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ a neighborhood basis at $x$, given arbitrary $x \in S$?

For all $N \in \mathfrak{N}(x)$, from our openness definition, $N$ are open as $N \subseteq N$. Then the sets $N \in \mathfrak{N}(x)$ are neighborhoods of $x$. This seems counter-intuitive as neighborhoods need not be open. But here I am.
Given a neighborhood $K$ of $x$, by definition of a neighborhood, there is an open set $U \subseteq K$ with $x \in U$, then $U$ contains an element from $\mathfrak{N}(x)$, so does $K$.

Hence the set $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ is a neighborhood basis at $x$.
Next, we check whether this topology is well-defined or not.

$\varnothing$ is vacuously open. $S$ is also trivially open.
Given $U, V$ open, is $U \cap V$ open? Let $x \in U \cap V$, then $\exists N \in \mathfrak{N}(x)$ with $N \subseteq U$ and $\exists M \in \mathfrak{N}(x)$ with $M \subseteq V$. From property (2) given in the problem, $\exists P \subseteq (N \cap M)$, such that $P \subseteq U\cap V$ and $P \in \mathfrak{N}(x)$. Thus intersections are open.
Unions are trivially open.

I do not know how this topology is uniquely determined.

Your (Eq.1) does not really make sense to me. You're quantifying over $x\in S$, but also every element you're writing down is already a union over all $x\in S$? It's important to keep in mind that a neighborhood of a point need not be an open set in the topology, so that explains why your first attempt was not enough. I suggest working backwards from a characterization of open sets in terms of neighborhoods (do you know one?).

@Thorgott I've edited the notation of Eq. 1, I meant to take all elements of N(x)'s for all x's. But I think I can understand your point about going in this direction, kind of arbitrarily trying. Bredon does not mention a characterization of open sets in terms of n'hoods up to this prb. Do you think this now-deleted def'n from  Wiki page of open set is sufficient: "A set is open if it's a n'hood of all of its points." If it is, I will learn more about it and later update the question. How do you suggest that I proceed? I will attempt once more today. Thanks a lot.

Yes, that cited characterization is good! If you combine this with the definition of a "neighborhood basis", this actually forces you to define the topology in a certain manner, so you basically get uniqueness for free and then you only need to verify the definition actually works. This is the direction you should proceed in.

@Thorgott I've attempted to a solution on your suggestion. My reasoning could be complete nonsense but it makes enough sense at the moment. If it is really inaccurate, what should I do, as in whether delete the question or wait if an answer comes up or wait until I grasp the solution and type? I've checked on the technicalities of posting questions on MathSE but I'm not sure on this. Thanks!

You're on the right track, but your definition does not quite make sense. The set $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ is itself a collection of subsets of $S$ containing $x$ and it's the elements of $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ that you want to be the neighborhoods. Your definition asks $\mathfrak{N}(x)\subseteq U$, which does not match the intuition (you're asking for a set of subsets of $S$ to be contained in a subset of $S$).

Hi @Thorgott , I added another doubtful attempt. Since elements of $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ can get "smaller" it seemed more natural to have this definition, as I've edited in the body in "2nd Attempt". Syntactically, proof seems okay to my eye but something feels wrong as here all neighborhoods turned out to be open, counter-intuitively. I feel like I need to review all the relevant definitions in the problem. Any further help is appreciated, thanks for all the help so far!

Your 2nd Attempt is great. Indeed, you have written down the correct definition. If you recall that a set in a topology is open if and only if it contains a neighborhood of any of its points, you see that any topology satisfying that $\mathfrak{N}(x)$ is a neighborhood basis of $x$ for any $x\in X$ has to be the topology you've written down. This establishes uniqueness. The arguments in your bullet points are all correct, except for the very first bullet point. I recommend as a bonus to make it explicit where you have used the assumption 3..
Now, your argument in the first bullet point is incorrect. To verify that $N\in\mathfrak{N}(x)$ were open as you claim, you need to verify that, for any $y\in N$, there is an $N_y\in\mathfrak{N}(y)$ s.t. $N_y\subseteq N$. For $y=x$, you can take $N_y=N$ as you do, but for any other $y$, there is no guarantee you can find such an $N_y$. Indeed, there is actually no guarantee that $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ at all: The exercise is incorrect. (I apologize for not pointing this out earlier.)
For an easy counter-example, consider $X=\{x,y,z\}$ and take $\mathfrak{N}(x)=\{\{x,y\}\}$ and $\mathfrak{N}(y)=\mathfrak{N}(z)=\{\{x,y,z\}\}$. This trivially satisfies 1.-3., but there is no topology on $X$ with these neighborhood bases. Indeed, in such a topology, the only open set containing $y$ or $z$ would be $X$ itself, so $\{x,y\}$ cannot be open, but since $\{x\}$ itself cannot be open either, $\{x,y\}$ is not a neighborhood of $x$.
To fix the Exercise, you have to introduce another axiom relating the neighborhood bases at different points of $X$ (it is hopefully intuitive that, to specify a topology, you need to have some sort of compatibility between the neighborhood bases at various points). This is discussed here.

Your step-by-step guide to the answer was really helpful, especially for developing a lot of intuition for nhoods and nhood bases. Thank you.
